# In Jenkins, How do I send emails only when the branch failed is the master branch?

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to write a script in pre-send script (from Editable-Email Notification plugin) to send the email (set the cancel flag to true) ONLY when the branch failed is a master branch (as in have master in the name of the branch). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to trigger an email based on a specific condition for a successful build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396606/how-to-trigger-an-email-based-on-a-specific-condition-for-a-successful-build-in)

your git plugin holds a env varible or you can make a env variable with branch name. then use the above solution to drop mail.

GIT Plugin provides you the env variable

> GIT_BRANCH - Name of the remote repository (defaults to origin), followed by name of the branch currently being used, e.g. "origin/master" or "origin/foo"

Comment: thanks for the reply, how do i create an env variable with branch name? and where do i create it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245570/how-to-get-current-branch-name-in-git      you can get the local branch name using this.  i have t check on git plugin

Comment: hey.. there is an env variable called "GIT_BRANCH"    in  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin. you can use that directly